# I am unable to install ggplot, there occurs some error

Tags: r, ggplot2

there is this long error message when i try to install ggplot, please someone help me. Thanks!

> install.packages("ggplot2")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/HP/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> also installing the dependency ‘rlang’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
rlang    0.3.4  1.0.1              TRUE
ggplot2  3.1.1  3.3.5             FALSE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1080437 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpwfvrv8\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3063309 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

- installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
  ** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'rlang' 0.3.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
- removing 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggplot2'
  Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\HP\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpwfvrv8/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.3.5.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpwfvrv8\downloaded_packages’

Answer (score 0):

It's saying your "rlang" version is outdated. Update that, it should be fine. Update all the libraries, that's a good practice while installing packages. (you do the same from tool option in menubar of Rstudio and update package)